# Filter Slicer in execl using PHP

Tags: php

How to read or write data in slicer for pivot in excel using PHP.
I am using COM extension and able to store pivot with slicer but how can i change value while storing in slicer

```
// EXCEL APP OBJECT
$xlapp =  new COM("Excel.Application") or Die ("Did not instantiate Excel");

    // WORKBOOK AND WORKSHEET OBJECTS
       $wbk = $xlapp->Workbooks- 
       >Open("C:\\xampp\htdocs\Filter_slicer\PivotTest.xlsx");
       $wks = $wbk->Worksheets(2);
       $wks1 = $wbk->Worksheets(1);

       // SET CELL VALUE
       $test = $wks->PivotTables();
       $test->Slicers();

       $wbk->save();
```

Comment: pls see the code mentoned above ineed code to edit the slicer in excel

Comment: @AdrianMole Any help

Comment: That's definitely improved the question (I've retracted my "close vote")! But this isn't really my field of expertise - hopefully, others will now help.